# JavaScript JSON call will only load once

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a onclick calling searchSymbol() which works perfectly fine on the first attempt. However, it only works once. What do I need to do in order to make sure my alert(tickerSymbol) is working multiple times? I am changing the "Ticker" value each buttonClick by textField.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="searchTicker" placeholder="Ticker Symbol..." required>
<input type="button" id="searchButton" onclick=searchSymbol() required>
<script type="text/javascript" id="myScript"></script>
```

**.js**

```
function searchSymbol() {

    var ticker = document.getElementById("searchTicker").value;
    document.getElementById('searchTicker').value='';


    var url="http://ir.stockpr.com/service/quote_jsonp?symbol=";
    var extra="&jsonp=quote_search";
    document.getElementById('myScript').src = url+ticker+extra;

}



function quote_search(json) {

    var tickerSymbol = json.symbol
    alert(tickerSymbol)

}
```

This alert will only work on the first click of my button. Im not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
alert(tickerSymbol)
```

Comment: You're changing the `src` to the same value, so nothing happens.

Comment: I am updating "Ticker" on every click. so it is not the same value.

Comment: Is myScript a script tag (<script>)?

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Like SLaks said, you are not updating the value of ticker. Are you meant to be adding `+1` to it?

Comment: Folks, I imagine @husharoonie is changing the text in the `#searchTicker` field each time. I think the problem is that changing the `src` property of a `<script>` element does not cause the script to be re-loaded

Comment: yes i am changing the text each time in the textField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the src of a script tag won't make it GET the new src. You would have to GET the JSONP programatically by creating a new script tag, like this:

```
function searchSymbol() {

  var ticker = document.getElementById("searchTicker").value;
  document.getElementById('searchTicker').value='';


  var url="https://ir.stockpr.com/service/quote_jsonp?symbol=";
  var extra="&jsonp=quote_search";

  // Remove already existing script tag
  if(document.getElementById('myScript'))
    document.getElementById('myScript').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('myScript'));

  // Create script tag and add it to head
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = url+ticker+extra;
  script.id = 'myScript';
  document.head.appendChild(script)

}

function quote_search(json) {
  // Check if we get anything in response
  if(json && json.symbol){
    var tickerSymbol = json.symbol
    alert(tickerSymbol)
  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if there's any real benefit in removing the old `<script>` element but I'm sure it doesn't hurt either

Comment: What is the nest way to check "json.symbol" value is not retriving anything?

Comment: @husharoonie To check whether the JSON API returns any value or not, then your best bet is to use AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) instead

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: Never mind my last comment, saw it was JSONP you were dealing with now - updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that assigning the `src` of a script will cause it to reload. You need to create a new script tag.

```
function searchSymbol() {

    var ticker = document.getElementById("searchTicker").value;
    document.getElementById('searchTicker').value='';

    var url="http://ir.stockpr.com/service/quote_jsonp?symbol=";
    var extra="&jsonp=quote_search";
    var newscript = document.createElement("script");
    newscript.src = url+ticker+extra;
    document.head.appendChild(newscript);

}
```